# deploying yii2 project using application load balancer with aws ssl certificate

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, aws-application-load-balancer

I am deploying my yii2 project on aws and using application load balancer with aws ssl certificate. the problem is that whenever $this->redirect(..) is called the url is changed to http instead of https and the browser shows "This site can’t be reached" (load balancer handles only https). I want to force all redirect actions to set the url to https.

**update**

I changed baseUrl for the url manager to https://mywebsite.com to solve this problem. now it appears only on user loggin and logout. where goHome() and goBack() actions are used

Comment: My guess is that the load balancer is trying to access the web application using http instead of https. That makes yii think that it should use http protocol for urls. Can you set your load balancer to access the application through https?

Answer (score 1):

The downside of your current solution is that you can not have multiple domains per app.
We have a very similar setup. Our loadbalancer is terminating the ssl and all other traffic is sent in internal network via http.

To accomplish your need make sure that the header `X-Forwarded-Proto` is set to `https`

And configure the request component to not remove `X-Forwarded-Proto` (via `secureHeaders`) or configure `$trustedHosts` so the header filter will not remove any secure headers at all.

For example:

```php
'request' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\Request',
            'enableCsrfValidation' => true,
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'YOUR COOKIE KEY',
            'csrfCookie' => [
                'httpOnly' => true,
                'secure' => true
            ],
            'secureHeaders' => [
                // Common:
                'X-Forwarded-For',
                'X-Forwarded-Host',
                //secure headers are filtered out if they are sent from not trusted remote hosts.
                
                //'X-Forwarded-Proto',

                // Microsoft:
                'Front-End-Https',
                'X-Rewrite-Url',
            ]
        ],
```

After that `getIsSecureConnection()` will return true, correctly, and your redirect urls will be generated as https.